# calculate date add, but only weekdays

Tags: vb.net, date

I would like to calculate a new date simply by using the build-in dateadd function, but take into account that only weekdays should be counted (or 'business days' so to speak).

I have come up with this simple algorithm, which does not bother about holidays and such. I have tested this with some simple dates, but would like some input if this can be done in better ways.

This sample assumes a week with 5 business days, monday-friday, where first day of the week is monday. Dateformatting used here is d-m-yyyy, the sample calculates with a startdate of october 1, 2009.

Here is the simple form:

```
Dim d_StartDate As DateTime = "1-10-2009"
Dim i_NumberOfDays As Integer = 12
Dim i_CalculateNumberOfDays As Integer 

If i_NumberOfDays > (5 - d_StartDate.DayOfWeek) Then
    i_CalculateNumberOfDays = i_NumberOfDays
Else
    i_CalculateNumberOfDays = i_NumberOfDays + (Int(((i_NumberOfDays + (7 - d_StartDate.DayOfWeek)) / 5)) * 2)
End If

MsgBox(DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, i_CalculateNumberOfDays, d_StartDate))
```

Which I try to explain with the following piece of code:

```
''' create variables to begin with
Dim d_StartDate as Date = "1-10-2009"
Dim i_NumberOfDays as Integer = 5

''' create var to store number of days to calculate with
Dim i_AddNumberOfDays as Integer 


''' check if amount of businessdays to add exceeds the 
''' amount of businessdays left in the week of the startdate
If i_NumberOfDays > (5 - d_StartDate.DayOfWeek) Then


    ''' start by substracting days in week with the current day,
    ''' to calculate the remainder of days left in the current week
    i_AddNumberOfDays = 7 - d_StartDate.DayOfWeek

    ''' add the remainder of days in this week to the total
    ''' number of days we have to add to the date
    i_AddNumberOfDays += i_NumberOfDays

    ''' divide by 5, because we need to know how many 
    ''' business weeks we are dealing with
    i_AddNumberOfDays = i_AddNumberOfDays / 5

    ''' multiply the integer of current business weeks by 2
    ''' those are the amount of days in the weekends we have 
    ''' to add to the total
    i_AddNumberOfDays = Int(i_AddNumberOfDays) * 2

    ''' add the number of days to the weekend days
    i_AddNumberOfDays += i_NumberOfDays

Else

    ''' there are enough businessdays left in this week
    ''' to add the given amount of days
    i_AddNumberOfDays = i_NumberOfDays

End If

''' this is the numberof dates to calculate with in DateAdd
dim d_CalculatedDate as Date
d_CalculatedDate = DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, i_AddNumberOfDays, d_StartDate)
```

Thanks in advance for your comments and input on this.

Comment: I think your algorithm is not giving a correct result for 10-jan-2009 (26-jan-2009) when the correct result is 27-jan-2009.

Comment: Indeed. I forgot to mention that I use dd-mm-yyyy formatting over here. So when I compile it says 1-oktober-2009. Sorry for that, will alter the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your plan seems like it should work.  Make sure you wrap it in a function instead of doing out the calculations every place you use it so that if/when you discover you need to account for holidays, you don't have to change it in tons of places.

The best way I can think of for implementing support for holidays would be to add days one at a time in a loop.  Each iteration, check if its a weekend or a holiday, and if it is add another day and continue (to skip it).  Below is an example in pseudocode (I don't know VB); no guarantees its correct.  Of course, you need to provide your own implementations for isWeekend() and isHoliday().

```
function addBusinessDays(startDate, numDays)
{
    Date newDate = startDate;
    while (numDays > 0)
    {
         newDate.addDays(1);
         if (newDate.isWeekend() || newDate.isHoliday())
             continue;

         numDays -= 1;
    }
    return newDate;
}
```

My first thought for the holiday thing was to simply look up the number of holidays between the start date and the end date and add that to your calculation, but of course this won't work because the end date is dependent on the number of holidays in that interval.  I think an iterative solution is the best you'll get for holidays.

Comment: I agree with you for not simply adding the number of holiday (what if, for example, the holiday falls in a weekend?). Thanks for your function (indeed, this stuff should always be put in a function).

Comment: FYI, newDate.addDays(1); should be newDate = newDate.addDays(1); addDays(1) RETURNS the date + 1, but does NOT update newDate itself.

Answer (score 1):

```
Public Shared Function AddBusinessDays(ByVal startDate As DateTime, _
                                       ByVal businessDays As Integer) As DateTime
    Dim di As Integer
    Dim calendarDays As Integer

    '''di: shift to Friday. If it's Sat or Sun don't shift'
    di = (businessDays - Math.Max(0, (5 - startDate.DayOfWeek)))

    ''' Start = Friday -> add di/5 weeks -> end = Friday'
    ''' -> if the the remaining (<5 days) is > 0: add it + 2 days (Sat+Sun)'
    ''' -> shift back to initial day'
    calendarDays = ((((di / 5) * 7) _
                   + IIf(((di Mod 5) <> 0), (2 + (di Mod 5)), 0)) _
                   + (5 - startDate.DayOfWeek))

    Return startDate.AddDays(CDbl(calendarDays))

End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

I used the .DayOfWeek function to check if it was a weekend. This does not include holiday implementation. It has been tested. I realize this question is old but the accepted answer didn't work. However, I did like how clean it was so I thought I'd update it and post. I did change the logic in the while loop.

```
Function AddBusinessDays(startDate As Date, numberOfDays As Integer) As Date
    Dim newDate As Date = startDate
    While numberOfDays > 0
        newDate = newDate.AddDays(1)

        If newDate.DayOfWeek() > 0 AndAlso newDate.DayOfWeek() < 6 Then '1-5 is Mon-Fri
            numberOfDays -= 1
        End If

    End While
    Return newDate
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this code to calculate the date:

```
    dayOfWeek = startDate.DayOfWeek
    weekendDays = 2 * Math.Floor((dayOfWeek + businessDays - 0.1) / 5)
    newDate = startDate.AddDays(businessDays + weekendDays)
```

The second line computes the number of full weekends that we have to add and then multiplies them by 2 to obtain the number of days.

The additional -0.1 constant is used to avoid adding days if (dayOfWeek + businessDays) is multiple of 5, and final date is friday.

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Function AddBusinessDays(ByVal dtStartDate As DateTime, ByVal intVal As Integer) As DateTime

    Dim dtTemp As DateTime = dtStartDate

    dtTemp = dtStartDate.AddDays(intVal)

    Select Case dtTemp.DayOfWeek
        Case 0, 6
            dtTemp = dtTemp.AddDays(2)
    End Select

    AddBusinessDays = dtTemp

End Function
```

Comment: I'm not sure if any of these solutions are properly handling the addition of more than 5 business days

Answer (score 0):

please check this code for adding working days

```
Dim strDate As Date = DateTime.Now.Date
Dim afterAddDays As Date
Dim strResultDate As String
Dim n As Integer = 0

For i = 1 To 15
    afterAddDays = strDate.AddDays(i)
    If afterAddDays.DayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Saturday Or afterAddDays.DayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Sunday Then
        n = n + 1
    End If
Next

strResultDate = afterAddDays.AddDays(n).ToShortDateString()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Function AddXWorkingDays(noOfWorkingDaysToAdd As Integer) As Date

    AddXWorkingDays = DateAdd(DateInterval.Weekday, noOfWorkingDaysToAdd + 2, Date.Today)
    If Weekday(Today) + noOfWorkingDaysToAdd < 6 Then AddXWorkingDays = DateAdd(DateInterval.Weekday, 2, Date.Today)

End Function
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this may be a valid answer, you are much more likely to help others by explaining what the code does and how it works. Code-only answers tend to receive less positive attention and aren't as useful as other answers.

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to iterate from the start date and add or subtract one day with each iteration if the date is not a Saturday or Sunday. If zero is passed as iAddDays then the function will return dDate even if that date is a Saturday or Sunday. You could play around with the logic to get the outcome you are looking for if that scenario is a possibility.

```
 Public Function DateAddWeekDaysOnly(ByVal dDate As DateTime, ByVal iAddDays As Int32) As DateTime
    If iAddDays <> 0 Then
        Dim iIncrement As Int32 = If(iAddDays > 0, 1, -1)
        Dim iCounter As Int32

        Do
            dDate = dDate.AddDays(iIncrement)
            If dDate.DayOfWeek <> DayOfWeek.Saturday AndAlso dDate.DayOfWeek <> DayOfWeek.Sunday Then iCounter += iIncrement
        Loop Until iCounter = iAddDays
    End If

    Return dDate
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy way

```
function addWerktage($date,$tage){
    for($t=0;$t<$tage;$t++){
        $date   = $date + (60*60*24);
        if(date("w",$date) == 0 || date("w",$date) == 6){ $t--; }
    }
    return $date;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This produces the same result as the accepted answer, including starting on weekends, while handling negative offsets and without looping.  It's written in c# but should work in any enviroment where numeric weekdays start at Sunday and end at Saturday, and where integer division rounds to 0.

```cs
public static DateTime AddWeekdays(DateTime date, int offset)
{
    if (offset == 0)
    {
        return date;
    }
    // Used to calculate the number of weekend days skipped over
    int weekends;
    if (offset > 0)
    {
        if (date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday)
        {
            // Monday is 1 weekday away, so it will take an extra day to reach the next weekend
            int daysSinceMonday = -1;
            // Add two weekends for every five days
            int normalWeekends = (offset + daysSinceMonday) / 5 * 2;
            // Add one for this Sunday
            int partialWeekend = 1;
            weekends = normalWeekends + partialWeekend;
        }
        else
        {
            // It will take this many fewer days to reach the next weekend.
            // Note that this works for Sunday as well (offset -1, same as above)
            int daysSinceMonday = date.DayOfWeek - DayOfWeek.Monday;
            // Add two weekends for every five days (1 business week)
            weekends = (offset + daysSinceMonday) / 5 * 2;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // Same as the positive offset case, but counting backwards.
        // daysSinceFriday will be 0 or negative, except for Saturday, which is +1
        int daysSinceFriday = date.DayOfWeek - DayOfWeek.Friday;
        weekends = date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday
            ? (offset + 1) / 5 * 2 - 1
            : (offset + daysSinceFriday) / 5 * 2;
    }
    return date.AddDays(offset + weekends);
}
```

Since the pattern of 2 extra days per 5 days repeats after a full week, you can effectively exhaustively test it:

```cs
private static DateTime AddWeekdaysLooping(DateTime date, int offset)
{
    DateTime newDate = date;
    int step = Math.Sign(offset);
    while (offset != 0)
    {
        newDate = newDate.AddDays(step);
        if (newDate.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Sunday && newDate.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Saturday)
        {
            offset -= step;
        }
    }
    return newDate;
}

void TestWeekdays()
{
    DateTime initial = new DateTime(2001, 1, 1);
    for (int day = 0; day < 7; day += 1)
    {
        for (int offset = -25; offset <= 25; offset += 1)
        {
            DateTime start = initial.AddDays(day);
            DateTime expected = AddWeekdaysLooping(start, offset);
            DateTime actual = AddWeekdays(start, offset);
            if (expected != actual) {
                throw new Exception($"{start.DayOfWeek} + {offset}: expected {expected:d}, but got {actual:d}");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
Dim result As Date
    result = DateAdd("d", 2, Today)
    If result.DayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Saturday Then
        result = DateAdd("d", 2, result)
        MsgBox(result)
    ElseIf result.DayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Sunday Then
        result = DateAdd("d", 1, result)
        MsgBox(result)
    ElseIf result.DayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Monday Then
        MsgBox(result)
    ElseIf result.DayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Tuesday Then
        MsgBox(result)
    ElseIf result.DayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Wednesday Then
        MsgBox(result)
    ElseIf result.DayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Thursday Then
        MsgBox(result)
    ElseIf result.DayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Friday Then
        MsgBox(result)
    End If
```